# Sitemap and 2 URLs pointing to the same page

Tags: sitemap, ranking

I have recently put my site of 17 years with Wix. It is going down fast in Google rankings.

My home page in Wix has the slug `/home-1` but my site is just `example.co.uk/`  when I search the `home-1` it says:

> The specified canonical link points to a different page.

In google search console it is indexing the one without the slug but it is not on the sitemap. I am guessing the `/home-1` is on the sitemap.

Would this be correct?

Comment: What does "put my site of 17 years with wix" mean?   Does that mean you recently moved your site to Wix, or that you have been using wix for 17 years?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the canonical link points to the root (`example.co.uk/`), and that is what you want. Remember that changes to the indexing instructions that you set for your website may take a while before being reflected in the Google SERPs (if Google ever accepts them).